# How to use subqueries in insert into?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am trying to insert data into the `emp_danil` table from the `dname` column by using a subquery.

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO emp_danil (dname)
    SELECT dept.dname
    FROM dept, emp_danil demp
    WHERE dept.deptno = emp_danil.deptno;
```

Table before query

```
+------+--------+-------+
| DATA | DEPTNO | DNAME |
+------+--------+-------+
| ...  |   10   | NULL  |
| ...  |   20   | NULL  |
| ...  |   30   | NULL  |
+------+--------+-------+
```

'Dept' table

```
+--------+------------+----------+
| DEPTNO |   DNAME    |   LOC    |
+--------+------------+----------+
|     10 | ACCOUNTING | NEW_YORK |
|     20 | RESEARCH   | DALLAS   |
|     30 | SALES      | CHICAGO  |
+--------+------------+----------+
```

Table after query:

```
+------+--------+-------------+
| DATA | DEPTNO |     DNAME   |
+------+--------+-------------+
| ...  |   10   | ACCOUNTING  |
| ...  |   20   | RESEARCH    |
| ...  |   30   | SALES       |
+------+--------+-------------+
```

The error :

> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("STUDENT"."EMP_DANIL"."EMPNO")

Comment: Your query does not really make sense to me. I am wondering whether you want an `INSERT` query (that creates new records) or an `UPDATE` (that modifies existing record(s)). Sample data and expected results would help understanding your question better.

Comment: Sample data and expected output ??

Comment: It should be clear that you're only trying to populate `emp_danil.dname` column while there exists some other column(s) with `not null` constraint.

Comment: `INSERT` means "create a new row". `UPDATE` means "change column value(s) in an existing row".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `update`:

```
update emp_danil e
    set dname = (select d.dname from dept d where d.deptno = e.deptno);
```

That said, you should not be storing `dname` twice.  It should only be in the `dept` table.  You can fetch the name using `deptno` and proper `JOIN` synax.